# Google Product Sans font in Android Application, okay to use?

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I've seen the Google Product Sans font in quite a few popular apps on the Play Store, and available to download from a few places. (https://9to5google.com/2018/05/09/google-sans-vs-product-sans/)

However, upon visiting the Google Fonts page for Product Sans it displays this message: https://fonts.google.com/license/productsans

> Google offers many fonts under open source licenses. This is not one of them. Please see fonts.google.com for options you can use.

Does not open source mean that we simply can't modify it, but we can use it? Would I be allowed to use this font in my Android application if I don't modify the font at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you cannot use it. It has nothing to do with whether you modify it or not.

If something is open source, you may be able to use it, depending on the license and how you intend to use it. But in this case the fonts are not open source at all.

Comment: I see, thank you. What about the popular apps that use this font? Are they unknowingly not following guidelines? Solid Explorer and Sync for Reddit are such examples with themes that include this font.

Comment: No idea. Here's another thread about it if you are interested: https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-download-the-Google-Product-Sans-font. There are several other really nice sans fonts listed there that are open source. Not sure why you'd want to mess with it.

Comment: @BryanWalsh while font copyright is legally difficult, google could sue them etc: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2891/what-are-the-consequences-of-using-unlicensed-fonts or maybe simply ban them from their app store, whatever hurts more.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's a beautiful font in my opinion, over the Open Sans alternative.